# Several ports open to the public (0.0.0.0/0)

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I was told by Amazon that my ports are open to public 0.0.0.0/0 . But still no idea on how to closed. Kindly help.

I had setup iptables and other rules, but this quite new for me.

My Operating system is Ubuntu
Lightsail Instance
Using Bitnami

To my limited knowledge I had only enable 80,443,22

[image]

The below is the text from Amazon---

We see that you've denied outbound connections to the IP of the destination domain , however in reviewing your Amazon EC2 instance(s), it appears you have left several ports open to the public (0.0.0.0/0). Leaving ports open like this can leave your instance vulnerable to compromise and unwanted network activity in general.

TCP     22     0.0.0.0/0
TCP     80     0.0.0.0/0
TCP     443     0.0.0.0/0

Comment: `SSH` uses port 22, `Nginix` and `Apache` use ports 80 and 443... Usually... But Your installation may vary. Run `sudo netstat -peanut | grep -i listen` to see the list of listening ports and their owners.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please specify Ubuntu version, include your current firewall setup and EC2 network topology to help readers diagnose your problem.

Comment: @BernardWei I had updated my question , thanks

Comment: Why are the Amazon guys even bothering to tell you about this? If you run a website how are you supposed to let readers reach it if you close ports 80 and 443?

Comment: @WayneTun Check that you have a security group added to this EC2. Under Inbound, remove all the rules and add the port you wish to open, 22, 80 and 443.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Amanzon instance new? When creating a new instance in step "6 Configure security group" indicates which ports will open for ssh or apache, etc.

Check in your instance that these are not with the anywhere 0.0.0.0/24 option

Port 22 would only add the ips or networks that will be able to access.

The other ports understand that they may be open if they are displaying a web page.

I am not very familiar with aws but if I find information I will add it to you.

Edited: I have found these pages that you may want to read. Where it explains what I told you about port 22, but on ports 80 and 443 you have to be with the tcp-udp protocol.

You can edit this if you go to the created instance, select it and below you get all its settings that you can change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingsecurity-groups.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule

I don't think you have to close the ports from ubuntu. You can try this and if it does not work start closing them from ubuntu with iptables, also check that you have the inactive ufw in ubuntu with the command

`ufw status`

If it is active I would recommend disabling it.

`ufw disable`

With this command you can know which ports are open and listening.

`netstat –pnltu | grep LISTEN`  or
`netstat –pnltu | grep ESCUCHAR`

Comment: you mean `0.0.0.0/0`, right?  `/24` would only work for 0.0.0.0-255, and that's not what they want :p

Comment: Yes, I meant `0.0.0.0/0`